# Contact Form 7, Calculate Quote show price on submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am using contact form 7 on a website and i want a calculate quote function where the user enters how many meters wide and long the driveway is and the type of finish the concrete is. After they enter the details in the form, they hit calculate quote and the price shows up.

At the moment, as soon as the sizing changes (wide/long) the price shows up.

How do i make it on click to show the price. I've been racking my brains. (relatively new to jquery)

website page is http://x.aiadstaging.com.au/projects/fdmconcreting.com.au/calculate-quote/

contact form 7 form code and jquery is:

```js
// wpcf7_caculate_quote.js
function caculate_quote($form, ev) {
 var $ = jQuery, $quoteTotal = $form.find('.quote-total');
 var $drivewayMeters = $form.find('[name="driveway-meters"]');
 var $footpathMeters = $form.find('[name="footpath-meters"]');

 var $finish = $form.find('[name="finish"]');
 var $totalQuote = $form.find('[name="total-quote"]');
 var total = 0;
 total = parseInt( $drivewayMeters.val() );
 total += parseInt( $footpathMeters.val() ) * parseInt($finish.val().replace(/^\$(\d+) /, '$1'))

 $totalQuote.val( total );
 $quoteTotal.html( '$' + $totalQuote.val() );
 if( total > 0 ) {
  $form.find('.head-title').removeClass('hide');
  $form.find('.your-info').removeClass('hide');
  
 } else {
  $form.find('.head-title').addClass('hide');
  $form.find('.your-info').addClass('hide');
 }
 return;
}
function hasEmptyValues($elements) {
 var res = false, $ = jQuery;
 $elements.each(function() {
  if( $.trim(this.value) == '') {
   res = true;
   return false;
  }
 });
 return res;
}
jQuery(function($){
 var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form.wpcf7-form');
 for( var i=0; i<forms.length; i++) {
  (function($form) {
   if( $form.find('#contact-me, #email-quote, #caculate-quote').length == 3 ) {
    // caculate_quote.call($form[0], $form);
    var $line1 = $form.find('[name="email-phone"], [name="your-name"], [name="post-code"]');
    var $line2 = $form.find('[name="your-email"], [name="your-name1"], [name="post-code1"]');
    $line1.bind('change.submit', function(ev) {
     if( hasEmptyValues($line1) ) {
      $form.find('.btn-contact-me').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
     } else {
      $form.find('.btn-contact-me').removeAttr('disabled');
     }
    });
    $line1.change();

    $line2.bind('change.submit', function(ev) {
     if( hasEmptyValues($line2) ) {
      $form.find('.btn-email-quote').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
     } else {
      $form.find('.btn-email-quote').removeAttr('disabled');
     }
    });
    $line2.change();

    var j=0, $elements = $form.find('select.change-quote, input.change-quote');
    for(j=0; j < $elements.length; j++) {
     if( $elements[j].type == 'submit' ) {
      continue;
     }
     if( $elements[j].type == 'checkbox' || $elements[j].type == 'radio' ) {
      $($elements[j]).bind('click.caculate', function(ev) {
       return caculate_quote.call(this, $form, ev);
      });
      continue;
     }
     $($elements[j]).bind('change.caculate', function(ev) {
      return caculate_quote.call(this, $form, ev);
     });
    }
    
    $form.unbind('submit.caculate').bind('submit.caculate', function(ev) {
     // ev.preventDefault();
     // return false;
     return caculate_quote.call(this, $form, ev);
    });
    var data = $._data( forms[i] ), firstClick = false;
    if( data && ('events' in data) && ('submit' in data.events) && (data.events.submit.length > 1) ) {
     if( data.events.submit[1].namespace == 'caculate' ) {
      var bk = data.events.submit[1];
      data.events.submit[1] = data.events.submit[0];
      data.events.submit[0] = bk;
      bk._handler = bk.handler;
      bk.handler = function(ev) {
       var $yourInfo = $form.find('.your-info');
       if( firstClick ) {
        caculate_quote.call($form[0], $form);
        firstClick = true;
       }
       if( $yourInfo.hasClass('.hide') || 
        !$.trim( $yourInfo.find('[name="email-phone"]').val() ) || 
        !$.trim( $yourInfo.find('[name="your-name"]').val() ) || 
        !$.trim( $yourInfo.find('[name="post-code"]').val() ) || 
        !$.trim( $yourInfo.find('[name="your-email"]').val() ) || 
        !$.trim( $yourInfo.find('[name="your-name1"]').val() ) || 
        !$.trim( $yourInfo.find('[name="post-code1"]').val() ) 
        ) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        return false;
       }
       return bk._handler.call(this, ev);
      }
     }
    }
   }
   
  })( $(forms[i]) );
  
 }
});
```

```html
<div class="head-title text-center hide">
<h3 class="form-title"><span class="underline">Quote Total:</span> <span class="orange quote-total">0</span></h3>
<p>excludes <span class="orange">GST</span></p>
<p>Would you like us to contact you about this quote?</p>
<div style="display:none">[text total-quote id:total-quote class:total-quote]</div>
</div>
<div class="your-info line clearfix hide">
<div class="line contactme clearfix">[text* email-phone id:email-phone class:email-phone placeholder "Email or Phone No"][text your-name id:your-name class:your-name placeholder "Your Name"][text post-code id:post-code class:post-code placeholder "Post Code"][submit id:contact-me class:btn-contact-me "Contact Me"]</div>

<div class="line quote clearfix">[email* your-email id:your-email class:your-email placeholder "Email Address"][text your-name1 id:your-name1 class:your-name1 placeholder "Your Name"][text post-code1 id:post-code1 class:post-code1 placeholder "Post Code"][submit id:email-quote class:btn-email-quote "Email Quote"]</div>
</div>

<div class="line clearfix"><h2 class="underline orange">Step 1</h2>How wide is your driveway?: [number* driveway-meters min:0 id:driveway-meters class:driveway-meters class:change-quote "10"] meters</div>

<div class="line clearfix"><h2 class="underline orange">Step 2</h2>How far is your garage from the footpath?: [number* footpath-meters min:0 id:footpath-meters class:footpath-meters class:change-quote "20"] meters</div>

<div class="line clearfix"><h2 class="underline orange">Step 3</h2>Choose your concrete finish:  [select* finish  id:finish class:finish class:change-quote "$65 sq/m|Plain" "$80 sq/m|Coloured Concrete" "$120 sq/m|Exposed Aggregate" "$120 sq/m|Stenciled"] <span class="icon-info"></span></div>
<div class="line text-center clearfix">[submit id:caculate-quote class:btn-caculate-quote "Caculate Quote"]</div>
```